# Reading URL parameter with spaces in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to pass a URL parameter to my SSRS report, but the value has spaces and unfortunately I can't change that at this time. The spaces are causing the parameter to pass like this (after Sport=):

`.aspx?Student=23252&Sport=Mens%20Baseball`

I believe the `%20` is preventing my report from reading the data and therefore I'm not producing results. Is there a way to get SSRS to read this without changing the way the value is stored in the database?

Comment: %20 is space in Encoded url
When you see “%20,” it represents a space in an encoded URL
Ref: https://www.fullhost.com/blog/what-does-20-mean-in-a-web-address/

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I'm not sure if there's a way to get my ssrs report to accept that as a parameter value.  The article you referenced mentions a PHP function that may possibly assist but I'm not familiar enough with PHP to know how to check that.

Comment: There should not be any issues passing in a URL with spaces. What the full URL? I assume you are opening a report via the URL and that URL has the parameters in it. One thing to note is the parameters passed in must be the parameter values, not the labels. The student value looks fine but the sport value, are you sure that is a valid value and not a label?

Comment: The parameters for the url are being passed based off a selection on a previous page.  I tested each parameter individually and this is the one causing my issue of not displaying data on the report.  Unfortunately the value is the same as the label in that they both have spaces.  My thought was that it was seeing the %20 and comparing it against the value, not recognizing that it's encoded?

Comment: why not replace the %20 with a space when you pass the parameters if you believe that is what is causing the issue?